# Extending vector bundles from a specific affine variety to its neighborhood

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let's consider the collection of four lines $x=0,x=1,y=0,y=1$ in $\mathbb{A}^2$, we denote it by $S$. The variety $S$ is basically $\text{Spec}(k[x,y]/(xy(x-1)(y-1)))$. Let $\text{Spec}(R)$ be a smooth affine scheme over a field (finite field or its algebraic closure if necessary). We consider a vector bundle on $\text{Spec}(R)\times S$, where on each side is just a pullback of a fixed vector bundle on $\text{Spec}(R)$. On intersections of the sides they get identified by an automorphism (In fact any vector bundle on $\text{Spec}(R[x,y]/(xy(x-1)(y-1)))$ is in this form). Let's assume the monodromy around the four lines is not trivial, this possibly can prevent us from extending the vector bundle from $\text{Spec}(R)\times S$ to the whole $\text{Spec}(R)\times \mathbb{A}^2$. Is it possible to at least extend the vector bundle to an open in $\text{Spec}(R)\times \mathbb{A}^2$ that contains $\text{Spec}(R)\times S$?

Remarks:

1. Determinant of the monodromy automorphism is $1$. Especially if you pullback this vector bundle to any closed point of $\text{Spec}(R)$ times $S$. It is a trivial vector bundle.
2. The affine scheme $\text{Spec}(R)$ is an affine in a smooth projective variety. The vector bundle on $\text{Spec}(R)\times S$ is a restriction of a vector bundle from the product of the projective variety and $S$.

Edit: Here another question that might be easier. Is it possible to extend the vector bundle to a coherent sheaf where restriction of the coherent sheaf to the infinitesimal neighborhood of $\text{Spec}(R[x,y]/(xy(x-1)(y-1)))$ in $\text{Spec}(R[x,y])$ is a vector bundle?

Edit: It seems to me (I could be wrong), it is easy to extend the vector bundle to the completion of $\text{Spec}(R)\times S$ along $\text{Spec}(R)\times \mathbb{A}^2$. On each line let's say for $x=0$, there seems to be a pullback from the line to the formal completion of the line. So we can pullback the vector bundle on each line to its completion under this pullback. We then glue all these vector bundles on formal completion exactly with the same gluing isomorphism that is used to glue the vb on $\text{Spec}(R)\times S$. But I'm not sure whether it is possible to extend this from completion to the whole $\text{Spec}(R)\times \mathbb{A}^2$ as a coherent sheaf.

Comment: Your "square" $S$ is not an algebraic variety, what is the meaning of a vector bundle on $S$?

Comment: $S$ is not irreducible. It consists of 4 components that are glued at the intersections. A vector bundle on it can be defined by defining vector bundles on each line with some isomorphisms on the intersections. (You can look at it as a scheme if that helps)

Comment: $S$ as a scheme is $\text{Spec}(k[x,y])/(xy(x-1)(y-1))$.

Comment: The name "square" is misleading, as @abx I was confused at first.

Comment: Say $R=k$. If $E$ is a vector bundle on $S$ which extends to an open $U\subseteq\mathbf{A}^2$, then it extends to a coherent sheaf $F$ on $\mathbf{A}^2$ (coherent sheaves always extend). Let $G$ be the reflexivization of $F$, then $F\to G$ is an isomorphism over $U$, and hence $G$ also extends $E$. But $\mathbf{A}^2$ is regular of dimension two, so every reflexive coherent sheaf is locally free. Thus $G$ is a vector bundle which extends $E$. Since vector bundles on $\mathbf{A}^2$ are trivial, $G$ is trivial, and hence so is $E$.

Comment: @Piotr Achinger Correct. The condition that determinant is 1 automatically implies that the vector bundle is already trivial. It follows from the fact every element in $SL_n(k)$ is generated by elementary matrices and you can deform them to identity.